# First instance of the flying saucer as a space craft?

Tags: spaceship, history-of, science-fiction-genre, origins, flying-saucer

A common idea of a spaceship, especially an alien spaceship, is the classic flying saucer, like the one below:

[image]

**What is the *first* instance of a flying saucer as a space craft in science fiction?**

Bonus question: if the first instance is *not* a film or television series, then *what is the first instance of a flying saucer as a space craft in television or film?*

Comment: @user14111 not at all - as long as it's a disk-shaped spacecraft that's fine, I don't really care what it's called

Comment: I remember reading that the shape is a misunderstanding. Someone claimed he saw flying ships that were shaped like crescent moons but "hopped" in the air like saucers (I don't remember the wording exactly) and the statement was misremembered as him having seen saucer-shaped things. I guess the science fiction ones came after this real statement (whether it was a real story is another matter).

Comment: There is a tag for flying brooms, but none for flying saucers?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93537/what-was-the-first-sci-fi-work-to-feature-a-spaceship?lq=1) about spaceships as a whole?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the **earliest science-fictional flying saucers** were in the **1887** novel *Bellona's Bridegroom: A Romance* (aka *Bellona's Husband: A Romance*) by ["Hudor Genone"](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/genone_hudor), pseudonym of William James Roe. At any rate, that's the earliest of four stories listed under "flying saucers" in the Motif and Theme Index of [Everett F. Bleiler](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/bleiler_everett_f)'s [*Science-Fiction: The Early Years*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0873384164). Here is part of Bleiler's review:

> A fanciful ideal society. * The narrator is Archibald Holt, a rather stupid middle-aged man who invests money in Professor Ratzinez Garrett's hydrogenium, a metallic form of hydrogen that is so light as to amount to antigravity. Garrett builds a flying disk using hydrogenium as a lifting agent, and Holt, Garrett and a third character (Trip) set out for Mars. * As they pass Phobos and Deimos they see that they are abandoned flying saucers much like their own. They later learn that the space craft came from Jupiter or Saturn, and that similar saucers have visited earth, but have flamed or crashed on entering the atmosphere. * The terrestrials land on Mars, which is like the eastern United States, and find a completely human race that speaks English. At first Garrett postulates that the similarity is due to colonists from earth (and is upset at the possibility that his patent may be invalid), but later decides that the similarity is the result of parallel evolution.

The **first flying saucer movie** was [*The Flying Saucer*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0042469/), released **January 5, 1950**. [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flying_Saucer):

> *The Flying Saucer* is the first feature film to deal with the (then) new and hot topic of flying saucers. Flying saucers or alien craft shaped like flying disks or saucers were first identified and given the popular name in 1947 when on June 24, 1947, private pilot Kenneth Arnold reported nine silvery, crescent-shaped objects flying in tight formation. A newspaper reporter coined a snappy tagline: "flying saucers" which captured the public's imagination.

All right, so that's the first flying saucer *movie*. What about **television?** I wonder if [*Captain Video*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Video_and_His_Video_Rangers) had any flying saucers before 1950?

Comment: It'd be nice to know the actual wording in *Bellona's Bridegroom*, unfortunately it seems to be a very rare book, not available on amazon or abebooks or anywhere else. Still, I think this is the answer--in that quote Bleiler mentions both a "flying disk" and "abandoned flying saucers", so it's pretty clear the original book must have identified the crafts as disk-shaped.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Yes, it's too bad we have to take Bleiler's word for it. Seeing as how Bleiler read more or less everything, and we're looking for the very oldest example, it's not too surprising that we end up with a rare book. If I cared a lot more, I could try and get a copy on interlibrary loan, and try to read it.

Comment: The wiki article [UFOs in fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFOs_in_fiction) shows a movie serial (though not a full length movie) featuring flying saucers that predates *The Flying Saucer*, the 1949 serial [Bruce Gentry – Daredevil of the Skies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Gentry_–_Daredevil_of_the_Skies), though apparently they are designed by a human villain--*The Flying Saucer* is the earliest one listed with an alien flying saucer.

Answer (score 8):

[This article](http://www.visualnews.com/2011/11/28/frank-r-paul-a-cornerstone-of-science-fiction-art/) claims that the cover of the November 1929 issue of *Science Wonder Stories* by artist Frank R. Paul is "the first illustration of a flying saucer, almost two decades before the first sightings by [Kenneth Arnold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_Arnold)" (as described [here](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/08/10/insider/1947-flying-saucers-land-in-the-times.html?_r=0), Arnold's 1947 claim initiated a rash of flying saucer sightings and caused 'flying saucers' to enter the public vocabulary):

[image]

The bottom of [this page](http://www.frankwu.com/Paul-8.html) also quotes a physicist and skeptic named [Milton Rothman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milton_A._Rothman) identifying this cover as the first inspiration for later flying saucer sightings.

You can see some galleries of Frank R. Paul cover illustrations [here](http://www.frankwu.com/paul1.html), [here](http://www.frankwu.com/paul2.html) and [here](http://www.frankwu.com/paul3.html)--you can see he liked to pick unusual shapes for his spaceships, including some later disc-shaped crafts such as [this one](http://www.frankwu.com/Paul-7.html), [this one](http://www.frankwu.com/Paul-9.054.html), [this one](http://www.frankwu.com/Paul-14.5.html), and [this one](http://www.frankwu.com/Paul-9.3.html).

Comment: What is that thing doing with the Woolworth Building?? Something rude?

Comment: There are also tapestries and paintings depicting saucer type flying objects from the Middle Ages and the Renaissance.Some deploying rays and surface features.

Comment: @Ihor Sypko - Can you link to any examples that show a saucer or disk shaped flying object?

Comment: Who won the $300.00?

Comment: The distribution of prizes is given on [this page](http://www.frankwu.com/Paul-8.html) which was one of the links in Hypnosifl's answer.

Comment: @Hypnosifi I can not but saw a program on H2 'Ancient Aliens" which recounted the history of UFO sightings and depictions in detail with numerous examples spanning the last 20 plus centuries including rock carvings and western paintings.

Comment: @Ihor Sypko - Ancient Aliens is not a very trustworthy source, you might want to check out the documentary [Ancient Aliens Debunked](http://ancientaliensdebunked.com) which is supposed to be pretty good up until the end where the filmmaker brings in his own Christian fundamentalist belief in things like Noah's Flood and the Tower of Babel. There's a specific section debunking claims of UFOs in medieval art [here](http://ancientaliensdebunked.com/references-and-transcripts/ufos-in-ancient-art/), which is only 10 minutes long--I watched it and it seems quite convincing.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Not a gulible true believer and only assume non-doctored images were shown, silly me. Recall such being presented decades ago, nothing new in the misinterpretation of iconographic images which depict religeous themes but are misrepresented as technological entities observed by artists or reported to contemporary writers. Will wait for Klatu for explanation.

Answer (score 6):

If you look for a first reference in literature, as opposed to fiction, then the oldest reference must surely be the [*Vimana*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimana).

Described as circular flying machines with a central dome and windows, travelling with the speed of the wind while emitting a melodious sound.  The references date back some 6,000 years.

The [Vimana](http://www.bibliotecapleyades.net/vimanas/esp_vimanas_9.htm)  are the Chariots of the Gods.  The sun itself is said to be a Vimana, they are capable of travel beyond the Earth.

You will easily find many references to them around the web by the UFO hunters who consider any reference to ancient flight to be evidence of aliens.

Comment: I certainly don't wish to offend anyone.  I've altered the text to try to address this concern.

Comment: They may be rounded, but the depictions I see on google images show them not to be saucer-shaped, but more like the rounded temple shown [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ae/Ananta_vasudeva_temple_2.jpg).

Comment: Oh man, did Nina Paley and the talents working with her do a *hilarious* interpretation of the Vimana in [Sita Sings the Blues](http://sitasingstheblues.com)!

Comment: By the way, if you think the original texts suggest they could be saucer- or disc-shaped rather than the more beehive-like shape I see in most illustrations, could you provide a quote?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the earliest "sighting" (besides those depictions mentioned by others in the middle-ages/ancient era) [this](http://ufopop.org/fullimgmag.php?cid=ModernElectrics1911-12.jpg) magazine cover shows a depiction of a flying saucer from 1911, a more extensive list can be found [here](http://ufopop.org/ufopop_mags.php).

The closest real life plane would be [Circular Wing Aircraft](http://celticowboy.com/Round%20Aircraft%20Designs.htm), although early examples don't look too similar once you start getting into the 1930's you could argue that designs like the Avrocar (it was only able fly at an altitude of 1m but the design is there) are similar enough to be called flying saucers. Beyond that, the earliest design I can think of would be Da Vinci's [Aerial Screw](http://www.da-vinci-inventions.com/aerial-screw.aspx) which [some people even went through the effort of building](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEkOENzqGLU), when we look at Da Vinci's [sketches](http://s357.photobucket.com/user/rbarfly/media/airscrew1.jpg.html) it does have a saucer shape.

Comment: I think that magazine cover is showing a craft shaped like a short blimp or zeppelin, the first real zeppelin having been flown [in 1900](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeppelin_LZ_1). Look at the structural lines on it, it doesn't look disk-shaped to me, more like a short sausage.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I disagree that it looks more like a zeppelin. I will accept that early depictions are rudimental and that it slowly evolved into [the shape that we recognise today](http://www.nicap.org/images/Saucer.jpg). It's significant that the width is twice that of the height which gives it the look of two saucers placed together. The development of the shape of flying saucer wasn't a sudden moment but a slow development of expanding on others ideas over time. The structural lines could easily be pieces of sheet metal also.

Comment: Yes, the structural lines could be seams between plates of metal, my point was that their shape doesn't seem like what'd be on a disk. There's a better picture of the "space flyer" in Gernsback's book *Ralph 124C 41+* on [this page](http://books.google.com/books?id=qdf-GtJUwrwC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA216-IA1), the lines that look like horizontal cross-sections (or lines of latitude) don't appear to be perfect circles as on a disk, but instead seem to have rather straight sides as you'd expect for a blimp-shaped object. The wheels on the bottom also make more sense for a craft longer than it is wide.